# How to download Azure feed (Gradle) from Azure pipeline

Tags: maven, gradle, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server

I have a published artifact in azure feed. The artifact is of type gradle. I want to download the artifact from another pipeline, but received

`* What went wrong:
2022-08-02T09:06:39.551+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
2022-08-02T09:06:39.552+0300
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not download organization-utils-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (com.organization.apps.organization-utils:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:20220731.134455-6)
2022-08-02T09:06:39.552+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

> Could not get resource 'https://azuredevops..internal///_packaging/organization-utils/maven/v1/com/organization/apps/utils/organization-utils/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/organization-utils-1.0.0-20220731.134455-6.jar'.
> 2022-08-02T09:06:39.552+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
> Could not GET 'https://azuredevops.organization.internal///_packaging/organization-utils/maven/v1/com/organization/apps/utils/organization-utils/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/organization-utils-1.0.0-20220731.134455-6.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> 2022-08-02T09:06:39.552+0300
> [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
> `

Can someone help, I have added

`maven { url 'https://azuredevops.organization.internal/<organization>/<Project>/_packaging/organization-utils/maven/v1'  name 'organization-utils' authentication { basic(BasicAuthentication) }`
and settings.xml has the valid credentials.
Its strange to be able to publish and unable to download the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was the proxy setup.
I was behind a corporate proxy due to which the internal request going via proxy were showing 403.
I used nonProxyhost setting in my gradle.properties file and added the internal URL in it, which resolved the issue.

How I narrowed it down to the proxy-> I was able to publish the Azure artifact, So I started by adding and removing proxy. The moment I realized that by adding proxy it was unable to publish as well, hence  added this line in gradle.properties, I was able to download the artifact feed.

```
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=<url of the host>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).